# How to search by classname and in element with style 'display='none''

Tags: javascript, dom

**[My code](http://jsfiddle.net/9z8DT/1/)**

I have a problem with searching in javascript.

I need to look up both throughout the document and only the CSS class.

```
<span class="ID">153</span>
<span class="keywords">pararell processing, evolutionary algorithm, linear algebra algorithm, FPGA</span>
<span class="author">Oleg Maslennikow, </span>
```

I want to search **g** in **Oleg** but not in **processing**.

If i search i want to show hide elements, and after hide it..

In this case, I would like to be able to look after the class = '`author`'.

I would also like to be able to look at the elements that have style `display = 'none'` by showing that element and then keep it.

Can anybody help me?

**I dont want to use jQuery!**

Comment: Thanks, *now* I want to go read that article (or, possibly, chapter)...Also browser-sniffing? Really? And what's `var st = lis[i].firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;` this? Why not `lis[i].children[5]`?

Comment: Why do you need to explicitly select only `display; none`? If you show all of them, there's no harm in showing ones already shown.

Comment: `if ( navigator.appName /* is tested */ ) { alert( "use feature detection!!!"); }`

Comment: You should post your code here, not some other site. Keep it to a minimal example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @RobG In the Javascript tag, posting your code as a JSFiddle actually seems to help you get a quicker answer, because people can just jump right into debugging. And, when no link is provided, often enough there will be a comment to the tune of "Please make a fiddle with your code"... But it would of course be better to post the code here as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome browser it should support `document.querySelector()`

This is how you achieve what you need :

```
document.querySelector('span.author'); // to return span class="author"
```

It is supported in the below browsers:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. No worries about the while-loop it's just a short and revers version of a for loop.

```
var element_to_find;
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("author");

var len = list.length;
while (len--) {
    if (list[len].style.display == "none") {
        var element_to_find = list[len];
        alert("do what you want");
    }
}
```

Second: You cold create a class for "display:none"
So it woud be easier to find.

Style:

```
.hidden{ display:none }
```